NullPointerException en la inserción de datos en java
Me sale el siguiente error al realizar el programa 
Todo está realizado ocupando NetBeans IDE21. Los datos que quiero ingresar en la bd son el nombre y la contraseña; la estructura de dicha bd es la siguiente: y estas son las líneas de código dentro el apartado de registro:
package Interfaz;
    import ClaseSQL.Conexion;
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class Registro extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        Connection cx;
        public Registro() {
            Conexion conectar = new Conexion();
            initComponents();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setTitle("Registros a bd");
        }

,estas son las lineas correspondiente a la accion que quiero imprementar en el boton y ya
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try{
    PreparedStatement insertar=cx.prepareStatement("Insert into registro values(?,?,?)");
    insertar.setString(1, "0");
    insertar.setString(2, name.getText().trim());
    insertar.setString(3, pasw.getText().trim());
    insertar.executeUpdate();
    
}catch(Exception error){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
}
    }

, y este es el código dentro de la clase conexión que cree para reaizar las conexiones con la bd:
package ClaseSQL;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion 
{
    String bd = "accesos";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    Connection cx;

    public Conexion() 
    {
    }
    public Connection connectar() 
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            cx = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bd, user, password);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conecto con BD " + bd);
            return cx;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error a Conectar con BD " + bd);
        }
        return null;
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Conexion conectar = new Conexion();
        conectar.connectar();
    }
}


Buenas, Emiliano, bienvenido al sito. ¿Le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código como texto formateado.

Por otro lado, no aparece ahí donde asignas Registro.cx a Conexion.cx.

Hola Emiliano, bienvenido, para evitar que cierren tu pregunta, te sugiero que la edites, elimines las imágenes, y agregues el código como texto.

al parecer el problema es que no se asigna ningún valor a la variable "cx" que en teoría es la que retorna la conexión.
Debieras modificar tu constructor de la siguiente manera.
public Registro(){
   ///comentamos esta linea //Conexion conectar =new Conexion();
  //Llamamos al metodo connectar de la clase Conexion que es la que te deberia retornar la conexion segun tu codigo
  this.cx =new Conexion().connectar();
  initComponents();
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  thi.setTitle("Registros a bd");
}

Espero haberte ayudado.
